# IMAP library compatible with .NET Framework 2.0

Tags: imap, c#-2.0

Is there any free IMAP library that supports .NET Framework 2.0? 
As I know, the Imapx, InterImap,  S22.Imap and MailSystem.NET are not compatible with .net 2.0.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

[ImapX](http://imapx.codeplex.com) can be compiled under .Net 2.0 using LinqBridge. Please see this discussion thread for a download: [Does ImapX support .NET Framework 2.0?](http://imapx.codeplex.com/discussions/450597). The binaries for .Net 2.0 and 3.0 will be also available through the download section and Nuget starting from next library release.